# Looping through two queryset in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have 3 models,

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
     full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CandidateProjects(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="projects")
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class CandidateTools(models.Model):
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="tools")
    tool_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


def data_view(request):
    v = Candidate.objects.get(id=1)
    template_path = 'data.html'
    context = {'v': v}
    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(context)

   data.html
   It only shows the tools data not Projects.
   {% for i in v.tools.all %}
     <tr style="width: 50%;">
        <td>
            Social Media Website with Django
        </td>
        <td>
           VS Code
        </td>
     </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

In template, i have the object of Candidate. I want to show Tools and Projects data in a tabular format, like:
[image: Output I want]

Can anyone suggest how can i access both models in template only.

Thanks..

Comment: You can access the objects using reverse access. 
`candidate.projects` and `candidate.tools`
Whatever you define as related_name, you can use it to reverse access.

Comment: add your views.py

Comment: My views is so simple. And yes I can access data reversely. But how can I show both Tools data and Projects data in a single table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `zip` function like so, new views look like

```
def data_view(request):
    v = Candidate.objects.get(id=1)
    template_path = 'data.html'
    context = {'v': zip(v.tools.all(), v.projects.all())}
    template = get_template(template_path)
    html = template.render(context)
```

data.html looks like

```
{% for i in v %}
     <tr style="width: 50%;">
        <td>
            {{i.0.tool_name}}
        </td>
        <td>
           {{i.1.project_name}}
        </td>
     </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Note: this will work fine only when number of projects and tools are same

Comment: Yes, I can do that but zip function only take same count. If Tools have extra object, then it will omit those elements. Am I correct?

Comment: So is there any other way. Also, i[0] and i[1] is not working in template. Can you suggest the best way or any alternative way @Karan

Comment: Sorry, for that, In template you have to use like {{i.0}} and {{i.1}}

Comment: yes, thats work. Thanks for your help. I think there is no way the alter of zip as zip() only takes same number of objects from both side and removes other. @Karan